# Open sets - real analysis

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to prove that the set $(x,y)$ given by $x+y<0$ is open.

I was thinking of using the distance to the origin as the radius for the open ball but I realize that might not work. If someone could point me in the right direction that would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

The function
$$f\colon \Bbb R^2\rightarrow \Bbb R,\quad (x,y)\mapsto x+y$$
is continuous and the given set is
$$f^{-1}((-\infty,0))$$
can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

Call our set $\mathcal{O}$. Take $(x,y) \in \mathcal{O}$.

Then $x + y <0$

So there is some $\epsilon > 0$ such that $x+y + \epsilon < 0$ still holds.

Let $\mathcal{B}_{\epsilon/2}(x,y)$ be a ball of radius $\epsilon/2$ centered at $(x,y)$. Then every point in the ball also will have component sum less than $0$. So $\mathcal{B}_{\epsilon/2}(x,y) \subseteq \mathcal{O}$.

This shows that $\mathcal{O}$ is open.